# Subclassing Objective-C Classes in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using [MWPhotoBrowser](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser) in a Swift project. One problem is that a subclass of MWPhotoBrowser will fail to compile with such error:

> :0: error: cannot override 'init' which has been marked unavailable

My code here:

```
class BrowseController: MWPhotoBrowser {
override init() {
    super.init()
    initialize()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initialize()
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    initialize()
}
...
```

And here are all the initializers of the parent class:

```
// Init
- (id)initWithPhotos:(NSArray *)photosArray  __attribute__((deprecated("Use initWithDelegate: instead"))); // Depreciated
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id <MWPhotoBrowserDelegate>)delegate;
```

Overriding these initializers in my subclass does not help. But if I create a subclass MyBrowser in Objective-C and then subclass from this class, everything works fine.

```
@interface MyBrowser : MWPhotoBrowser
- (id)init;
@end

@implementation MyBrowser
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {}
    return self;
}
@end

class BrowserController: MyBrowser {
...
```

I'm using Xcode 6.1. Is this a Swift bug or did I miss something about Swift intializers? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chanitorn's answer isn't quite correct, because `initWithDelegate:` isn't a designated initializer for MWPhotoBrowser, `init:` and `initWithCoder:` are.  The trick is to add them to public MWPhotoBrowser header and specify them as `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER`

`- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (id)init NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;`

[Here's my PR](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/pull/373/files)

Answer (score 1):

Seem the strictness of swift initializers is causing the issue.
try to use the NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER to define designated initializer in objective-c library class will solve this issue.

```
- (id)initWithPhotos:(NSArray *)photosArray  __attribute__((deprecated("Use initWithDelegate: instead"))); // Depreciated
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id <MWPhotoBrowserDelegate>)delegate NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```